# High-voltage frequency divider

Tags: frequency, high-voltage, frequency-divider

How can a frequency divider for high voltages be implemented? Is it possible to make it cheap and compact?

An application would be to mount it between the output of fluorescent lamp ballasts (delivering 20kHz at a high voltage above 500 volts) and the input of the lamp and change that frequency to control the flickering frequency of the lamp.

Comment: Your question seems confused. Please define 'high voltage' in numbers and do you actually need a **frequency divider** (giving 10kHz, 5kHz, 2.5kHz etc) or do you need a circuit to vary the frequency at that voltage?

Comment: I thought a frequency divider would be the easiest way to go but a frequency controller would be even better. I just need to make lamps distinguishable by their flicker frequency.

Comment: Why make lamps distinguishable in this way. What is your goal?

Comment: Indoor navigation

Comment: A really stupid question here:  Have you actually checked to see that the fluorescent lights really flicker at 20kHz?  I could imagine that the phosphorescent layer inside the tubes might not be capable of really flickering at that speed.  That may also be part of the reason for such a higher frequency - besides making the parts smaller and cheaper, it also eliminates flicker.

Comment: Wikipedia agrees, but says it needs a citation for it:  Fluorescent lamps using high-frequency electronic ballasts do not produce visible light flicker, since above about 5 kHz, the excited electron state half-life is longer than a half cycle,[citation needed] and light production becomes continuous.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamp#Phosphors_and_the_spectrum_of_emitted_light  (See Flicker problems)

Comment: So, stay below 5kHz.

Comment: @JRE thanks that is an important factor I need to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better and simpler way, in my opinion, is to alter a value of a component in the electronic ballast. The ballast circuit (usually) rectifies the incoming AC power to fuel a power oscillator that then drives the fluorescent tube. Here's a simple picture that should help in understanding: -

[image]

And below is a block diagram of one (this one has dimming facilities but ignore that: -

[image]

So, I would begin to look for EB circuits on the web and build one just to get a prototype then experiment with altering the oscillation frequency. Then replace the EBs in the lamps with the modified EBs

BUT PLEASE BE CAREFUL BECAUSE THESE THINGS CAN BE LETHAL.

The approach of using the existing EB and inserting something betweeen it and the lamp is basically using two EBs in series and the 2nd EB has to be developed in exactly the same way as what my preferred route is (above).

You also might be able to get an existing EB and alter its operating frequency a bit BUT without a circuit diagram you are somewhat in the dark (pun intended). I'll repeat what I said earlier: -

### PLEASE BE CAREFUL BECAUSE THESE THINGS CAN BE LETHAL.

Comment: First thanks for the nice answer. I thought about this too but it makes the setup a little bit less modular. I think having separate modules you can attach to any lamp (with a similar ballast of course) is more time efficient. If I may ask, which part of that circuit is responsible for the oscillation frequency? And what would change if an old ballast is used, syncing with the mains' frequency of 50 Hz?

Comment: If you are trying to use CFL,then go for cold cathode CFL,they Fluorescent tube is made for dimming purpose.These uses the LC tank circuit,the circuitry is quite complex as a high voltage is required for Ignition/starting ,and high current to keep the CFL running,the price tag of CFL are itself determined by these ballast design,For dimming purpose the cold cathode tube are designed to operate at wide range of running current.As you say you have a addon to these CFL please don't use those addons as these CFL have fixed Power factor any active component in your addon may disturb it.

Comment: @MaMba was this comment to the guy asking the question?

Comment: @Mehdi the half-bridge driver and tank circuit form the oscillator. You can't sync this with mains frequency - the incoming mains is rectified to DC - anyway why would you want to?

Comment: It was just a thought, if all lamps were in phase one could accurately measure the relative distance by measuring the phase shift on the photo-diode, but it is not that important to have it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could go the way of dimmable lamps (or ballasts with suitable lamps) and use a lower frequency intensity modulation to identify each lamp, if you want to have lots of lamps you could modulate the intensity of each with a simple code (morse code even :-)

There are store shelf tags that use the lights to send data and they may have a solution for a lamp modulator you can tailor to your application.

https://www.google.com/search?q=shelf+price+tags+digital&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=4diWVdLDBIfkyAPt9YMg&ved=0CB4QsAQ